# Can one generate a bib tag from the entry's title instead of from the author?

Tags: bibtex, citing

currently I am using `alpha` as bibliography style. In my case it would make much more sense to generate the short form from the title. At the moment for some autors (which are companies, because I refere to websites), it is counting to *k* an above.

Is there an style existing for my needs?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a minimum working example (MWE) that shows what you've done so far. How are you treating the `author` field in entries with corporate authors?

Comment: I am not sure if automatic abbreviations of the *title* are really more helpful for the reader than a `numeric` style. If you want to stick to `alpha` I would suggest to leave the `author` field empty in your website entries and manually specify a label to use with `label=` or `shorthand=`in the bib file. Both are supported by biblatex, for bibtex one has to check the actual styles.

Answer (score 1):

Using biblatex you could use `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` for this. By default the alphabetic style uses the `labelname` element, I changed this to `title`. My MWE for this looks like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@BOOK{Author2001,
  author = {Alastname, Afirstname},
  title = {Title},
  year = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

% Declare new label format
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
    \labelelement{
        \field[final]{shorthand}
        \field{label}
        \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{title}
        \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{title}
    }
    \labelelement{
        \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
    }
}

\begin{document}
Filler text \cite{Author2001}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Just a suggestion. I don't think the OP is using `biblatex`. Why don't you add in the answer something like "This can be done if you use biblatex, ..."?